# Flex datagrid printing issue with page size

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4

I need to print the following datagrid in A4 size page. It is not fitting with with page size and dataprovider is not working for the printdatagrid.Pleasecorrect me.

[image]

The current output is:

[image]

***My data grid :***

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dashboardList" width="100%" height="95%"
                                             alternatingItemColors="[0x373737, 0x373737]"
                                             borderColor="#FFFFFF" borderStyle="inset"
                                             chromeColor="#295A7D" contentBackgroundColor="#373737"
                                             dataProvider="{allTrancList}" fontWeight="normal"
                                             horizontalGridLineColor="#858585" click="productDatagrid_clickHandler(event)"
                                             horizontalGridLines="true" variableRowHeight="true"
                                             wordWrap="true">
                                    <mx:columns>
                                        <mx:DataGridColumn width="60" headerText="S.No"
                                                           labelFunction="serialNoLabelFunc2"/>                                 
                                        <mx:DataGridColumn width="60" dataField="trancCode"
                                                           headerText="Order ID"/>
                                        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="date" headerText=" Date"
                                                           labelFunction="getDateLabel"/>
                                        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="clientName"
                                                           headerText="Client name"/>
                                        <mx:DataGridColumn width="90" dataField="clientCode"
                                                           headerText="Client code"/>
                                        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="itemType"
                                                           headerText="Work/Product"/>
                                        <mx:DataGridColumn width="60" dataField="itemNumbers"
                                                           headerText="Count"/> 

                                        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="cost" headerText="Cost"/>

                                        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="discountAmount"
                                                           headerText="Discount"/>
                                        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="tax" headerText="Tax"/>

                                        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="total" headerText="Total"/>

                                        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="paymondmode"
                                                           headerText="Payment mode"/>
                                    </mx:columns>
                                </mx:DataGrid>
```

***My printData grid:***

```
<mx:PrintDataGrid id="myDataGrid" width="99%" height="100%">
        <mx:columns>

            <mx:DataGridColumn width="60" dataField="trancCode"
                               headerText="Order ID"/>

            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="clientName"
                               headerText="Client"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn width="90" dataField="clientCode"
                               headerText="Client code"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="itemType"
                               headerText="Type"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn width="60" dataField="itemNumbers"
                               headerText="Count"/> 

            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="cost" headerText="Cost"/>

            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="discountAmount"
                               headerText="Discount"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="tax" headerText="Tax"/>

            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="total" headerText="Total"/>

            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="paymondmode"
                               headerText="Payment mode"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:PrintDataGrid>
```

***My  code for print:***

```
var thePrintView:FormPrintView = new FormPrintView();
                    addElement(thePrintView);

                    // Set the print view properties.
                    thePrintView.width=printJob.pageWidth;
                    thePrintView.height=printJob.pageHeight;
                    thePrintView.prodTotal = prodTotal;

                    // Set the data provider of the FormPrintView 
                    // component's DataGrid to be the data provider of 
                    // the displayed DataGrid.
                //  thePrintView.myDataGrid=PrintDataGrid(dashboardList);
                    thePrintView.myDataGrid.dataProvider =allTrancList;
```

Comment: have you tried setting variableRowHeight="true" wordWrap="true" on PrintDataGrid and set other properties to as you have done for dashboardList datagrid. Like:- <mx:PrintDataGrid id="myDataGrid" width="99%" height="100%" variableRowHeight="true" wordWrap="true" etc......>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for [AlivePDF](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/) or [PurePDF](http://code.google.com/p/purepdf/), Both options will provide you more space to spread your wings with lots of possibilities and can cater ever changing requirements.

Please find code below (this code is just an insight about the possibility in respect to your requirement, and you can find whole lib of test files from purePDF site [linked above])-

```
package
{
import flash.events.Event;

import org.purepdf.colors.RGBColor;
import org.purepdf.elements.Paragraph;
import org.purepdf.elements.RectangleElement;
import org.purepdf.pdf.PdfPCell;
import org.purepdf.pdf.PdfPTable;

public class PdfPTableColors extends DefaultBasicExample
{
    public function PdfPTableColors(d_list:Array=null)
    {
        super(["Customize border and background color","of table cells"]);
    }

    override protected function execute(event:Event=null):void
    {
        super.execute();
        createDocument();
        document.open();

        registerDefaultFont();

        var table: PdfPTable = new PdfPTable(4);
        table.widthPercentage = 100;
        var cell: PdfPCell;
        cell = PdfPCell.fromPhrase(new Paragraph("test colors:"));
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = PdfPCell.fromPhrase(new Paragraph("red / no borders"));
        cell.border = RectangleElement.NO_BORDER;
        cell.backgroundColor = RGBColor.RED;
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = PdfPCell.fromPhrase(new Paragraph("green / magenta bottom border"));
        cell.border = RectangleElement.BOTTOM;
        cell.borderColorBottom = RGBColor.MAGENTA;
        cell.borderWidthBottom = 10;
        cell.backgroundColor = RGBColor.GREEN;
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = PdfPCell.fromPhrase(new Paragraph("blue / cyan top border + padding"));
        cell.border = RectangleElement.TOP;
        cell.useBorderPadding = true;
        cell.borderWidthTop = 5;
        cell.borderColorTop = RGBColor.CYAN;
        cell.backgroundColor = RGBColor.BLUE;
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = PdfPCell.fromPhrase(new Paragraph("test GrayFill:"));
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = PdfPCell.fromPhrase(new Paragraph("0.25"));
        cell.border = RectangleElement.NO_BORDER;
        cell.grayFill = 0.25;
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = PdfPCell.fromPhrase(new Paragraph("0.5"));
        cell.border = RectangleElement.NO_BORDER;
        cell.grayFill = 0.5;
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = PdfPCell.fromPhrase(new Paragraph("0.75"));
        cell.border = RectangleElement.NO_BORDER;
        cell.grayFill = 0.75;
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = PdfPCell.fromPhrase(new Paragraph("test bordercolors:"));
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = PdfPCell.fromPhrase(new Paragraph("different borders"));
        cell.borderWidthLeft = 6;
        cell.borderWidthBottom = 5;
        cell.borderWidthRight = 4;
        cell.borderWidthTop = 2;
        cell.borderColorLeft = RGBColor.RED;
        cell.borderColorBottom = RGBColor.ORANGE;
        cell.borderColorRight = RGBColor.YELLOW;
        cell.borderColorTop = RGBColor.GREEN;
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = PdfPCell.fromPhrase(new Paragraph("with correct padding"));
        cell.useBorderPadding = true;
        cell.borderWidthLeft = 6;
        cell.borderWidthBottom = 5;
        cell.borderWidthRight = 4;
        cell.borderWidthTop = 2;
        cell.borderColorLeft = RGBColor.RED;
        cell.borderColorBottom = RGBColor.ORANGE;
        cell.borderColorRight = RGBColor.YELLOW;
        cell.borderColorTop = RGBColor.GREEN;
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = PdfPCell.fromPhrase(new Paragraph("orange border"));
        cell.borderWidth = 6;
        cell.borderColor = RGBColor.ORANGE;
        table.addCell(cell);

        document.add(table);
        document.close();
        save();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you give any link for adobe air  sample .?